# How to find duplicate value in one column against a unique identifier in another column?

Tags: sql

```
Table = MyTable
Column 1 = Key
Column 2 = Desc
```

There are a records in MyTable that have Key values and Desc value:

Example:

```
    Key   Desc
    1     Hello
    1     Hello
    2     Hello
    3     Hello
    4     Bonjour
    5     Hi
    6     Gutentag
    7     Yo
```

1. Only Key 1 can contain Desc Hello, meaning I need to find the other Key values that have the same Desc of Hello
2. The query must also filter out duplicates based on the previous logic

Expected result based on example:

```
    Key   Desc
    1     Hello
    2     Hello
    3     Hello
```

and NOT

```
Key   Desc
1     Hello
1     Hello
2     Hello
3     Hello
```

Comment: the question is tagged with sql server, oracle and mysql. which one are you actually using?

Comment: Did you try using `SELECT DISTINCT Key, Desc` with `WHERE Desc = 'Hello'`

Comment: I removed the three extraneous database tags.  Please feel free to add *one* tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Correct that would work for 'Hello', however I need a query that can return unknown Desc values also with a similar scenario, as to the above

Comment: I have tried to use GROUP BY, DISTINCT and HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: select  KEYID,VAL from table
GROUP BY KEYID,VAL

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.key,t.desc
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.desc like 'hello'
```

if you need it to work on any given desc than your should use it as a variable. To answer how to do it you need to tell us where are you getting the input from?

Comment: Hi John, how can I use Desc as a variable if that variable is to have more than one value. I have tried Table variables and inner joins to figure this out, but have not been successful.

Comment: Normally variables comes from other platforms. For example from a textField in your client code which is written in Java. Your program will pass the variable to your server and from there to the query. for example in java: String query = "select * from student where id=" + userid  - userid will be a variable. when you will run the query stmt.executeQuery(query) it will be whatever value userid has.

Comment: Understood, how can I pass desc as a variable via SQL Server 2008?